# Haskell : parallel list computation

Tags: haskell

I am trying to follow the implementation of the countdown problem shown in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlwSBNI9bXE&) and I thought it would be a good problem to try and run in parallel?

```
data Op =
    Add
  | Sub
  | Mul
  | Div deriving (Eq)

data Expr = 
    Val Int 
  | App Op Expr Expr

--{ helper functions }  

solutions' :: [Int] -> Int -> [Expr]
solutions' ns n =
  [e | ns' <- choices ns, (e, m) <- results ns', m == n]
```

I tried following some other posts on how to do this and came up with something like this

```
instance NFData Op where
  rnf Add = Add `deepseq` ()
  rnf Sub = Sub `deepseq` ()
  rnf Mul = Mul `deepseq` ()
  rnf Div = Div `deepseq` ()

instance NFData Expr where
  rnf (Val a)     = a `deepseq` ()
  rnf (App o l r) = (rnf  o) `deepseq` (rnf l) `deepseq` (rnf r)

solutions' :: [Int] -> Int -> [Expr]
solutions' ns n =
  ([e | ns' <- choices ns, (e, m) <- results ns', m == n]
    `using` parList rdeepseq)
```

It compiles but the program crashes when i try and run it. To be honest I was really just guessing on what I wrote.

How do I get this to run in parallel?

when I run in GHCI

```
>λ= r = (solutions' [1,3,7,10,25,50] 765)
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
>λ= mapM_ print r
*** Exception: stack overflow
>λ=
```

if i compile with
`ghc ./Countdown.hs +RTS -N8 -s`

and then run the executable, it does not terminate.

Comment: Would you please add the specific error you receive and a description of how you’re running the code? (Are you loading it in GHCi? Are you getting to a point where you can call `solutions'`, but it fails on the specific inputs you used? What are they? &c.)

Comment: @JonPurdy I have added it. Is what I tried to do correct?

Comment: Not an expert on the parallel package but - shouldn't the `m == n` filtering be outside of the parallel part?  At the moment it seems like you're parallelizing over a list of things that are already known to be successes, and most of the work on the elements must have already been done.

Comment: @DavidFletcher yes maybe. However at the moment, there seems to be something wrong with my Instances or how I am trying to run `deepseq` on the list because, the program does not complete. I would imagine if it was just a case of  the `m==n` then I would at least have a working program that does not have any parallel processes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I just clicked at a random timestamp in the video, and by sheer luck I got a slide that describes what's wrong.

> For our example, only about 5 million of the 33 million possible expressions are valid.

So, this means that you are evaluating

```
_fiveMillionList `using` parList rdeepseq
```

Now, the way `` (`using` parList _strat) `` works is that it immediately forces the entire spine of the list. When you begin evaluating your expression, `parList` forces all the cells of the list to exist. Further, as @DavidFletcher notes, your parallelism is actually useless. Because the filtration is underneath the `using`, forcing the entire spine of the list also forces all 33 million `Expr`s to exist, because you need to know how many elements passed the `(==)` test, so you need to create the `Expr`s to test them. They don't need to *all* exist simultaneously, but, in the end, 5 million of them (not counting the `Expr`s recursively contained in them), plus 5 million `(:)` constructors, will be held in memory. To add insult to injury, you proceed to create 5 million more objects in the form of dud sparks. And, all of this is being orchestrated by 5 million calls to the `Eval` monad's `(>>=)` function. I'm not sure which one of these exactly is sitting resident in memory for long enough to cause a stack overflow, but I'm fairly sure that `parList` is the culprit.

Perhaps try a more reasonable `Strategy`. I think you are pretty much forced into using `parBuffer`, because you need laziness. Using `parBuffer n strat`, if you evaluate a `(:)`-cell, then the strategy ensures that the next `n - 1` elements have been sparked. So, essentially, it "runs ahead" of any consumer that starts at the head of the list, maintaining a buffer of parallely-evaluated elements. Something like `parBuffer 1000 rdeepseq` should be fine.

---

Your `NFData` instances could use some work. They aren't the problem, but they don't really demonstrate a sound understanding of how evaluation works. I'll just leave them here:

```
instance NFData Op where
  -- (seq/deepseq) x y is defined by
  -- "if you want to evaluate (seq/deepseq) x y to WHNF, then you must
  -- evaluate x to WHNF/NF, then evaluate y to WHNF."
  -- but e.g. Add is already in WHNF and NF, so seq Add and deeqseq Add are no-ops
  -- the actual evaluation is already finished by the case in rnf's equations
  -- you could even write rnf x = x `seq` (), but I think it's best to be explicit
  rnf Add = ()
  rnf Sub = ()
  rnf Mul = ()
  rnf Div = ()

instance NFData Expr where
  rnf (Val a)     = a `deepseq` ()
  -- rnf o, rnf l :: ()
  -- WHNF and NF are the same thing for the type (); all constructors are nullary
  -- therefore (deepseq (rnf x) y) = seq (rnf x) y
  -- but then seq (rnf x) y = deepseq x y {by definition}
  rnf (App o l r) = o `deepseq` l `deepseq` rnf r
```

Comment: Thanks. With your changes, it now runs. 1957 sparks (all converted). I pulled the filter out of the `using` too. Program runs slower than before. Also the comments in your code are extremely helpful and educational